# Какое правило насчёт повторения предлогов?

Tags: предлоги

В комментарии к одному вопросу я написал: *"Это же сайт по русскому языку, а не программированию!"* И подумал через полчаса, что меня бы поправила Галина, как уже один раз поправила (я даже спросил Вас тогда, где мне найти на этот счёт правило, но Вы, видимо, уже не увидели комментария, Галина), и правильно повторить предлог: "а не ***по*** программированию".

*Собственно, вопрос тот же:* какие общие правила на этот счёт? Всегда нужно повторять предлоги или в каких-то случаях не надо? В каких тогда не надо или можно не повторять?

Comment: Я тут! ))) Везде ссылки на Розенталя и его примеры: http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/208/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85 Новенького ничего!

Comment: Нашла Розенталя с Былинским: http://texts.news/literaturovedenie_1041/117-predlogi-pri-odnorodnyih-52420.html

Comment: Вот, Галина, та фраза: "И ещё я буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, как правильно оформить, чтобы получился вопрос к первой фразе, т. е. фактически концу "списка". Почему обязательно повторить *к*, "к концу"? Интересно также, что остальные скажут.

Comment: Ну и?.. Остаюсь на позиции *к концу списка!*

Comment: Ёлки-палки, Галина, я ж не спорю с Вами (хоть и не уверен точно в Вашей правоте)! Я просто прошу каких-то пояснений. Пожалуйста, скажите, почему так правильно.

Comment: Тёмочка! Я ж писала, что с теорией у меня напряг! Практик мы сугубый!

Comment: Тогда я буду писать в таких случаях без предлогов по аналогии с английским. Хотя я, **конечно же,** согласен, что можно "к" повторить и это ничуть не хуже. То есть строго не хуже, но, на мой вкус, лучше без него. ;) Не навязываю, конечно, его никому!

Comment: Так у нас в Розентале семь пунктов обязательных и три факультативных: побеждает критическая масса!

Comment: Галина, предлог здесь действительно факультативен, опираясь на пункт 3 в конце списка. В письменной речи, конечно, можно поставить, но вот в устной речи, здесь трудно произнести предлог.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выбор факультативен и зависит более от благозвучия фразы, а не от строгих правил.

Но если хотите, обратитесь к рекомендациям Розенталя:

1. Предлог повторяется:

   - 1) если однородные члены соединены повторяющимися союзами, например: [Наталья] с жадностью вслушивалась и в бесхитростные песни жаворонков, и в скрип колодезного журавля, и в шелест напитанного полынной горечью ветра (Шолохов);
   - 2) если однородные члены соединены сопоставительными союзами, например: Он дрался и буянил не столько для собственного удовольствия, сколько для поддержания духа своего солдатства (Л. Толстой);
   - 3) если нужно показать, что предшествующее определение относится только к ближайшему однородному члену, например: выслушать с большим вниманием и с сочувствием;
   - 4) если отсутствие предлога может вызвать неясность в понимании предложения, например: учебники по литературному редактированию и по литературе (при пропуске второго предлога могло бы создаться впечатление, что речь идет об общих, а не об отдельных учебниках по двум предметам);
   - 5) при отдаленной смысловой связи между однородными членами, например: Пришлось много ездить по Украине, по степям Казахстана, по сибирской тайге (перечисленные слова не входят как видовые понятия в ближайшее родовое понятие);
   - 6) при значительном распространении однородных членов пояснительными словами, например: Пыль толстым слоем лежала на письменном столе, обитом зеленым сукном, на кожаном диване с широкой спинкой, на старом вольтеровском кресле.
     Иногда предлог повторяется перед группами однородных членов, образуемыми близкими по значению словами, например: ... За нею с кувшином, медным тазом, с простынями и губкой шла ее кухарка Ольга (Чехов).

Невозможен пропуск разных предлогов; ср.: на предприятиях и в учреждениях. Иногда по недосмотру предлог в этом случае опускается при длинном ряде однородных членов, когда вначале такой пропуск возможен, а в дальнейшем невозможен, например: «Много народу было на улицах, площадях, бульварах, переулках» (перед последним словом нужен уже другой предлог).

2. Факультативное повторение предлога встречается:

   - 1) если однородные члены соединены противительными союзами; ср.: Эта первая кормежка случилась не в поле, а в какой-то русской деревушке (Аксаков). – Конфликт можно было разрешить, прибегнув к переговорам, а не «силовым» действиям;
   - 2) если однородные члены соединены разделительными союзами, ср.: Другая река бежит по долине или по широкому лугу (Аксаков). – Последние слова подействовали на доктора сильнее, чем ссылки на человеколюбие или призвание врача (Чехов)
   - 3) Предлог обычно не повторяется в целях благозвучия (чаще, когда следующее слово начинается с того же согласного звука, которым выражен предлог), например: Плоты с кричавшими мужиками с гомоном и стуком стали уходить вверх по реке (Серафимович); Раскатывали брезентовые рукава к пруду или колодцу (Солоухин); а также: А другой раз вдруг с грохотом и плеском обрушилась в реку старая ольха (Паустовский).

[«Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке» Д. Э. Розенталь](http://www.tepka.ru/rozental_2/207.html)

Comment: 5-й пункт как-то не убедительно звучит!(( Я бы предпочёл сказать "по Украине, сибирской тайге, степям Казахстана". Есть ещё аргументы?

Comment: "Плоты с кричавшими мужиками, с гомоном и стуком стали уходить вверх по реке". Запятая вообще непонятна!! Как будто мужики и гомон со стуком — это однородные члены, и ***гомон и стук тоже везли на плотах***! РЖУНИМАГУ!)))

Comment: Да уж...Издержки интернет-ресурсов. Я там до конца и не прочитала - скопировала всё подряд.

Comment: Артем, вы хотите сказать, запятая не нужна?

Comment: Конечно, не нужна! А как же по-вашему? Вот Людмила тоже согласилась, исправила. Почему же она может быть нужна?

Comment: Артем, запятая стоит не только на этом сайте, а в именно в его справочнике. Без запятой получится: мужики кричали с гомоном. Что, согласитесь, не может быть. Смысл в том, что плоты уходили вниз с кричащими мужиками и гомоном ( Нестройный, неясный шум ) , т.е. мужики кричали, а плоты издавали неясный шум. Запятая вполне оправдана.

Comment: Не думаю. Плоты с кричавшими мужиками с гомоном и стуком стали уходить вверх по реке.Плоты какие-с  кричавшими мужиками, стали ухолить как?- с гомоном и стуком. - всё нормально. А чем же оправдана запятая? Это оборот? Тогда нужно было обособить с двух сторон - как пояснение. А с одной - никак.Запятая не нужна. А сайты копируют друг у друга, как и мы, на них смотреть нечего. Есть в тексте Серафимовича и без запятой.

Comment: Людмила, а как объяснить запятую в печатном издании справочника? Мне кажется, что здесь несогласованные определения при существительном плоты: ***плоты*** (какие?)с кричавшими мужиками,с гомоном и стуком. Что скажете?

Comment: Хотя, если вчитаться, вариант без запятой тоже возможен.

Comment: Да не возможен, а единственно верен, а вот плоты с мужиками, гомоном и стуком - смешно, это уходили они с гомоном и стуком.